# React DOM not updating after the browser/react server stopped supporting a component

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-server

Overnight, my originally working react service was disabled. The reason that it happens is my browser or react server stopped supporting this react component "react-selectize". React-selectize is a react component build on "react-select" and provide some extra feature. The DOM no longer update for the component. A quick fix would be to change component into react-select and abandon some features.

My question is, we didn't update our browser or any npm package, why would this change occurs overnight?

And I have a second question. 
I tried to insert a breakpoint to the code using chrome debugger, and I found this traceback message:

```html
action FETCH_USER_PENDING @ 16:00:44.155
redux-logger.js:1  prev state {notification: {…}, user: {…}}
redux-logger.js:1  action     {type: "FETCH_USER_PENDING"}
redux-logger.js:1  next state {notification: {…}, user: {…}}
localhost/:1 (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of webstore.binding did not set the binding field
localhost/:1 (WEB_PAGE context) Lazy require of runtime.binding did not set the binding field
2localhost/:1 Previous API instantiation failed.
redux-logger.js:1  action FETCH_USER_FULFILLED @ 16:00:59.515
redux-logger.js:1  prev state {notification: {…}, user: {…}}
redux-logger.js:1  action     {type: "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED", payload: {…}}
redux-logger.js:1  next state {notification: {…}, user: {…}}
localhost/:1 (WEB_PAGE context) extensions::event_bindings:8: Uncaught Natives disabled{<stack trace unavailable>}
localhost/:1 (WEB_PAGE context) extensions::binding:5: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Event' of undefined{TypeError: Cannot read property 'Event' of undefined
    at extensions::binding:5:38
    at extensions::runtime:7:28}
extensions::runtime:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Binding' of undefined
    at extensions::runtime:7
(anonymous) @ extensions::runtime:7
extensions::webstore:7 Uncaught Natives disabled
```

From my perspective, the react use lazy update mechanism in DOM, and the browser had a problem to do binding between new data and ui. Can someone help decipher the message a bit more? Ideally, I am looking for a fix (maybe using redux?) that could fix this issue without changing the react component. But I am open to all solutions.

Comment: It could be the proxy, as I am using a internal internet connection.

Comment: It turned out to be a component fails to update the DOM. The chrome decided to abandon the simple-select component in 'react-selectize'. I will update later.